# Splunk create table with counts based on differing value in a field

Tags: splunk

I am trying to create a table which counts the items in my list with splunk.

E.g. I have a list of items, with one item having the following fields:

- name
- type
- result (e.g. has only three values success, failure, N.A.)

I wish to create a table that groups the items into its respective names, and then count the number of items belong to that name and list the respective type of the group which contains the set of items. After which, I wish to have additional columns that split the counts into different columns based on the "tag" attribute.

Here's a sample table format I wish to achieve:

```
name      | type       | success | failure | N.A. | Total count
Item A    | fruits     |    5    |   0     |   1  |     6
Item B    | vegetables |    0    |   2     |   3  |     5
Item C    | sweets     |    1    |   3     |   2  |     6
```

Here's what I tried after looking up in the splunk command reference:

```
index="The index I am looking for" | stats count, values(fields.type) as type by fields.name | table fields.name, Type, count | rename fields.name as name, count as "Total Count"
| appendcols [search index="The index I am looking for" fields.result="success" | stats count, values(fields.type) as type by fields.name | table fields.name, Type, count | rename fields.name as name, count as "success"] 
| appendcols [search index="The index I am looking for" fields.result="failure" | stats count, values(fields.type) as type by fields.name | table fields.name, Type, count | rename fields.name as name, count as "failure"]
| appendcols [search index="The index I am looking for" fields.result="N.A." | stats count, values(fields.type) as type by fields.name | table fields.name, Type, count | rename fields.name as name, count as "N.A."]
```

I noticed that for some columns, e.g. column with the heading "failure", do not have their rows aligned with the other rows, resulting in the total count column not matching with all the counts in the rows being added up.

E.g. referencing from the table presented earlier, with the search query I created, the table below is generated:

```
name      | type       | success | failure | N.A. | Total count
Item A    | fruits     |    5    |   2     |   1  |     6
Item B    | vegetables |    0    |   3     |   3  |     5
Item C    | sweets     |    1    |   0     |   2  |     6
```

I'd appreciate if advice can be given on how to improve upon the search query, or if possible, to correct me on better suited commands to use.

Comment: `appendcols` is almost never the answer to a Splunk problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `appendcols` command works right under somewhat limited circumstances.  The order and count of results from `appendcols` must be *exactly* the same as that from the main search and other `appendcols` commands or they won't "line up".

One solution is to use the `append` command and then re-group the results using `stats`.

```
index=foo 
| stats count, values(fields.type) as Type by fields.name 
| fields fields.name, Type, count 
| rename fields.name as name, count as "Total Count"
| append [search index=foo fields.result="success" 
  | stats count, values(fields.type) as Type by fields.name 
  | fields fields.name, Type, count 
  | rename fields.name as name, count as "success"] 
| append [search index=foo fields.result="failure" 
  | stats count, values(fields.type) as Type by fields.name 
  | fields fields.name, Type, count 
  | rename fields.name as name, count as "failure"]
| append [search index=foo fields.result="N.A." 
  | stats count, values(fields.type) as Type by fields.name 
  | fields fields.name, Type, count 
  | rename fields.name as name, count as "N.A."]
| stats values(*) as * by name
| table fields.name, Type, count
```

Another solution avoids using `append` at all.

```
index=foo 
| rename fields.* as *
| stats count as "Total Count", 
        sum(eval(result="success")) as success,
        sum(eval(result="failure")) as failure, 
        sum(eval(result="N.A.")) as "N.A.", 
        values(type) as Type by name 
| table name, Type, success, failure, "N.A.", "Total Count"
```

The construct `sum(eval(<<expression>>))` counts the results where `<<expression>>` is true.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. The first method works for me! On a side note, may I know what does `stats values(*) as * by name` do? I'm not sure about what does the `*` mean in the command.

Comment: `stats values(*) as *` lists the unique values for all fields without having to name each field.  The `*` is a wildcard.